# Reloading whole ViewController after custom Button pressed in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I added 2 `UIButton` in my custom `UITableViewCell`.

When pressed something is done with the displayed object(in this case a User). Now I want the row/cell to disappear. My Idea was to reload the screen via triggering the `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` functions,
since i use `PFQueries` to obtain user data and display them in my table view.

What happens is, that other than deleting that row since my query shouldn't find the data, it just adds the same things again.

Is there a better way to solve this? I want to delete the row and redo my Query.

Comment: if you want to reload the contents of the table view, tableView.reloadData() will refresh the table view by calling the data source methods again. If you want to remove a row, check out tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPath()

Comment: Does this require the server call to delete the selected item from server as well or you want it just to perform with local object in the app?

Comment: What exactly is your issue here??? From the question it would seem "how to send the message to view controller from the cell when pressing a button"; the second paragraph seems "how to remove a cell from the table view"; the third paragraph seems to be indicating something is not working but the statement there makes no sense to me at all; The last is asking about better solution but I have no idea to what (better then what?) and then again having the issue on "how to delete a row" and "how to redo the query"?

Comment: I am assuming OP wants to know how to delete a row from a table.

Comment: I am trying reload the data within my table from a server request. The object is no longer to be found there - so that the cell must be deleted. The easiest way I figure is to reload the data + redo the server queries. but it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a row from a table, you can use a function like this:

```
// Add this function to your ViewController
func tableDeleteRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // IMPLEMENT ME:
    // first, remove the item from the data that drives the tableView.

    // This is what I do. Yours will be different.
    // self.tableData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    // tell the table to delete the row
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Code

        print("remove from table")
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

}
```

If you are looking to reload the entire table and redo the data you got from the server, do this:

```
// This is pseudo code.
func tableRefresh() {

    // this is a pseudo code function.
    // replace it with your own.
    get_data_from_server() {
        (data, response, error) in
        // do something with data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("refresh table")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to remove the row, but it will mix up my indexPath.row doesn't it? I am using some array and get my wanted data with array[indexPath.row]

Comment: What do you mean by "mix up my indexPath"? It won't mix up anything. The only thing you need to do now is to make sure that you remove the item from the data.

Comment: Sorry that was too implicit. all my arrays must be reorganized when deleting a row. that for i need them to be removed and filled again with the now new (correct) data. This is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Then use the guidance provided by the second code snippet I provided. Get your new data, then reload the table.